# IncompatibleClassChangeError while spring context initialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class. Please see server.log for more details.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldController': 
  Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory 
  org.meluk.billboard.business.controller.HelloWorldController.sessionFactory; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in 
  ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/billboard-servlet.xml]: 
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

My pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springVersion>3.1.0.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <hibernateVersion>3.5.4-Final</hibernateVersion>
    <junitVersion>4.8.2</junitVersion>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junitVersion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My spring config file:

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="org.meluk.billboard.business.controller" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/config/jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${hibernate.default_schema}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly set a spring-hibernate3 dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
<version>2.0.8</version>
```

It's not a coincidence that this is the bean you're getting the exception on.

You shouldn't need to do that; is there a reason you're not using spring-orm of the same version of Spring you're using? I haven't set an explicit hibernate3 dependency for quite some time.

Comment: 2.0.8 is the latest avaliable version.http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-hibernate3

Comment: @Balconsky What makes you think you need it?

Answer (score 2):

An `IncompatibleClassChangeError` means that JVM is getting contradictory information about some class.  This typically happens when you compile some code against one version of an class or interface, but then use a different version of that class / interface at runtime.  The problem is picked up at runtime when the JVM checks that the class and method signatures match.

In this case, the "Implementing class" message seems to be saying that the class that changed no longer implements some interface that it did originally.  (Maybe the package name changed.)

Somewhere in your log files there should be a message that names the classes that are causing the problem, but the expurgated versions of the stacktrace that you provided don't.

---

I'd say they are two possibilities.  One is that you've got a problem with the way you are doing your builds, and that you are not recompiling things that ought to be recompiled.  The other possibility is that you've got an inconsistent mix of JARs in your WAR file; e.g. you are somehow mixing JARs from different versions of Spring.

Comment: If I have inconsistent mix of jars in WAR file, how can I identify it? Which jar could be inconsistent?

Comment: If you could figure out which classes were conflicting, that would be a start.